# Display an editable Word document in a panel/iframe and also display editable SharePoint metadata in another panel/iframe

Tags: sharepoint, iframe, metadata, panel

Is there a way to make this possible? At moment I can't see anything available to make this easier than develop a custom solution.

Display an editable Word document in a panel/iframe and also display editable SharePoint metadata in another panel/iframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SkyDrive has an API, but my knowledge of this is limited.  From what I know, the documents must be associated to an account to be viewed or shared - so space is limited to the default of 7GBs.